# Cannot use hyphenation properly in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, hyphenation

I work mostly with old Slavonic and old Greek texts where there are plenty of  diacritical signs and every time when pasting text from word to InDesign, I have some problem with. For example, they are absent or improperly placed. I manage to cope with this, but the most annoying part is with slicing the word. In this example the word is *чръсль* and when double clicking InDesign doesn’t recognize this as a whole word and does not correctly hyphenate it: There is a linebreak between *ч* and *pъслъ*. In Word there are no such problems, I suppose the set of fonts is not the problem.

[image]

Another example:

[image]

What I have to do:  Compare these problem words with the original ones and just correct them. There are a lot of ways, but no way to make this automatically.

I thought because the font is not Unicode, this might be the problem, but maybe the Old Slavonic itself is. I do not know how the fonts work on this basis.

Comment: I don’t think InDesign has any hyphenating rules for Old Church Slavonic. I don’t think Word does, either, though. This isn’t really a problem with the app so much as it is a problem of there probably not being a Hunspell hyphenation dictionary available for OCS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I supposed with the old Church Slavonic signs we should  be more patient and little more work is required with widely opened eyes, I can just put hyphen off and use left align but then such words are just slicing when at the end of line. I have to mark them by hand and set not break. That is difficult.

Comment: Note that TeX *can* hyphenate Church Slavonic: See https://github.com/slavonic/cu-tex and https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/churchslavonic and ask on TeX.sx

Comment: It is debatable, but you don't really need to use hyphenation with "ragged right" justification.

Comment: I think hyphenation is not a big problem here, maybe  I have misled  with the title. I have difficulties with such words/texts in long flows where the words are broke /when at the end of the line/ and if you do not know Old Slavonic language you can not see the errors. And lot of corrections is needed after that. Thanks to everyone, I am just wondering if there is a way to improve my work.

Comment: @АнитаБорисова I don’t really understand what you mean, then. Slicing a word at the end of a line in two, putting the second half of it on the next line, and adding a hyphen where it was sliced is what hyphenation is. You mention double-clicking. Are you saying that when you double-click _črěslĭ_ in your InDesign document, instead of highlighting the entire word, it only highlights _rěslĭ_? If so, it sounds like there’s something like a zero-width non-joiner or a zero-width space between the č and the r. Have you tried showing all editing marks (Cmd + Alt + i) to see if this is the case?

Comment: I suppose you have to do it manually, since there's no slavonic dictionary. Seems there's no other way around it.

Comment: Looking into this a bit further, I think perhaps your font may be an issue/the issue here after all. Could you package an InDesign file where this occurs and make it available for us to inspect?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: ".. because the font is not Unicode .." then all bets are off. This would fully explain the erratic behavior of hyphenation (which assumes the character set is correct) and double-click selection (which assumes consecutive "word" characters – in Unicode).

Comment: @usr2564301 Ah, I missed that bit. That was exactly what I wanted to test for. Yes, with a non-Unicode font, you cannot possibly expect it to function correctly. (That bit was edited in by a different user, though… was there a comment made by Anita which was incorporated into the question by a different user and then deleted by a mod?)

Comment: Yes, this was my comment. I will be more careful with the rules when asking next time, I did not know how to make attachment in previously ask question. Thank you,  Wrzlprmft.